# Deleting (Destroying) Class Object That Belongs To Another Class Object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I am attempting to delete a class object that belongs to another class object but the destroy method is actually deleting the class object that `has_many` rather than deleting the singled out `belongs_to` class object. What am I missing here?

Animal.rb

```
class Animal < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :sightings, dependent: :destroy
end
```

Sightings.rb

```
class Sighting < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :animal
end
```

Sightings Controller

```
class SightingsController < ApplicationController

    def index
        @sightings = Animal.sightings.all
    end

    def create
        @animal = Animal.find(params[:animal_id])
        @sighting = @animal.sightings.create(sighting_params)
        redirect_to @animal
    end

    def new
        @animal = Animal.find(params[:animal_id])
        @sighting = @animal.sightings.create(sighting_params)
    end

    def edit
        @animal = Animal.find(params[:animal_id])
        @sighting = @animal.sightings.find(params[:id])
    end

    def update
        @animal = Animal.find(params[:animal_id])
        @sighting = @animal.sightings.find(params[:id])

        if @sighting.update_attributes(sighting_params)
            redirect_to @animal
        else
            redirect_to 'edit'
        end
    end

    def destroy
        @animal = Animal.find(params[:animal_id])
        @sighting = Sighting.find(params[:id])
        @sighting.destroy

        redirect_to root_path
    end

    private

    def sighting_params
        params.require(:sighting).permit(:animal_id, :date, :time, :latitude, :longitude)
    end
end
```

Delete Button (Using Bulma Classes FYI)
**Also, this is located in my ANIMAL `show.html.erb` file.**

```
<%= link_to "Delete Sighting ID#: #{sighting.id}", sighting_path(sighting), method: :delete, data: { confirm: "Are you sure you want to delete this sighting?" }, class: "button is-danger" %>
```

To my understanding, in order to delete/destroy a sighting of an animal, I need to collect the animal ID prior to deleting the sighting because the sighting belongs to the animal. I thought I was doing that but as I said above, the delete button is deleting the animal itself and not the actual specific sighting.

Thanks in advance for any help/clarification.

Answer (score 0):

```
class Animal
   has_many :sightings, dependent: :destroy
end
```

Dependent destroy will destroy all of the sightings when you destroy an `Animal`.

> I need to collect the animal ID prior to deleting the sighting because
>   the sighting belongs to the animal.

False. If you want to destroy a single sighting, you just need its ID:

```
def destroy
  @sighting = Sighting.find(params[:id])
  @sighting.destroy
end
```

> the delete button is deleting the animal itself and not the actual specific sighting

Frankly, if you've done your routing correctly, this is impossible. That button should go to the SightingsController. In your SightingsController, you *never* have `@animal.destroy` which is absolutely necessary for destroying an `Animal` given your model configuration.

You have either misconfigured your routes or you're showing us a different controller than the real one.